# Query to find out contacts in DataExtensions who have clicked or opened Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Consider a scenario where all contacts from DataExtension receives an Email. I want a query to retrieve all contacts who opens the Email.

Comment: For more details please go through **Data VIEWS** ... Example: query you can fine here to find Opens https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_opens_in_last_30_days_ref.htm&type=5

Comment: What are the column names you would like to retrieve from your DataExtension?

Comment: column names like FirstName and LastName.

Comment: Do you have a SubscriberKey column in your DE?

Comment: @zuzannamj What to do if there is no subscriberkey column in DE?

Comment: What column was used in the send relationship? Where it says: `xxx relates to subscribers on xxx`

Comment: @zuzannamj EmployeeId relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key

Comment: I updated the query in my anwser, you now just need to change `{{Data Extension Name}}` to the name of your Data Extension. If it has spaces or special characters in the name, put it in square brackets `[My Data Extension]`

Comment: @zuzannamj Thank you:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on which fields you want to retrieve from your Data Extension, you could do something like this. This will pull Sent Date, Open Date and Click Date for each subscriber in your Data Extension. I assume you have some sort of SubscriberKey column in your Data Extension:

```
SELECT 
de.EmployeeId,
de.FirstName,
de.LastName,
s.EventDate as SentDate, 
o.EventDate as OpenDate,
c.EventDate as ClickDate
FROM {{Data Extension Name}} de LEFT JOIN _Sent s ON de.EmployeeId = s.SubscriberKey
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID  and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
```

To make the above work, insert the name of your Data Extension to where it says `{{Data Extension Name}}`. For your convenience, you can run this query in [Query Studio](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/05/query-studio-for-marketing-cloud/).

Here's an article about [Data Views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) which explains what data is available in Marketing Cloud and how to correctly pull it.